# OpenCV set frame width&height caused to get empty frame

Tags: opencv, camera, gstreamer, camera-calibration

I have a Logitech C270 webcam. When I try to set its frame dimensions with OpenCV, I got an empty a frame.

```
cap.open(1);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
```

`cap.isOpened()` retuns true but `frame.empty()` is also returns true.

if I set dimensions 640x480 using the same code, I have no problem.

I know my camera works with 1280x720 because it works using `gst-launch-1.0` with 1280x720.

What should be the problem with OpenCV?

Comment: You have to read a frame before it will show up as not empty.

Comment: @MarkSetchell of course I read it :) cap >> frame;

Comment: The idea is that you show a **Minimum, Complete, Verifiable, Example** - with the emphasis on **complete** ;-)